# An open set containg all irrationals

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology and $A \cup\mathbb Q=\mathbb{R}$. Does it imply $A=\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 6):

No, I can remove any set of rationals that contains all its limit points.

So I could remove $\mathbb Z$ for example or $\{0\}\cup\{\frac 1n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ for example, or many more complex ones.

Comment: To illustrate the possible complexity: Tim's example is essentially the case $\alpha=\omega$ of the following: For any countable [ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\alpha$ there is a closed set of rationals whose order type is precisely $\alpha+1$. Its complement is open.